# Processing large number of text files with Apache Hadoop

Tags: apache, hadoop, text, mapreduce, data-analysis

I have a very large number of text files with a combined size of 1 TB. Let's say, I have to perform word count on each file and want to store the result of each file separately. Is Apache Hadoop the right solution for this kind of problem? The size of each file is 5 MB. I can not concatenate the files as I want to see the word count result of each file separately. What I want Hadoop to do is feed each file as input to a mapper and generate a separate output file for it at reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `WholeFileInputFormat.java` and `WholeFileRecordReader.java` here - https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/tree/master/ch08-mr-types/src/main/java
This will help you read content of one file as a record. I think you may have to tweak the InputFormat and RecordReader little bit to emit filename as the key.

In plain map-reduce I think it will be a Map only job, where each map task is responsible to for counting distinct words in a record ( which is the entire content of file). You can directly store the output of these map tasks which will give you word count for a single file.

I believe you are comparing your use case with the standard word count map reduce application where reducer is used to count the words across all of the input ( in your case all the files). You do not intend to do this hence I said you will not reducer here.

I am not sure if employing a reducer to count the words in a single file would be a good idea.

Other option would be to use the inputformat and recordreader mentioned above and use [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/) OR [Apache Pig](http://pig.apache.org) or some high level abstraction on top of map-reduce to simplify your work.